# SharePoint Online: Can a user be delegated permission to edit another user's User Profile?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile

In previous on-prem versions of SharePoint, you could add a user as an "Assistant" in User Profile, and that user would have the ability to edit their manager's user profile (see this link for reference: http://blog.bonzai-intranet.com/analysthq/2011/01/sharepoint-user-profile-assistant-field/) .  However, I'm trying the same thing in SharePoint Online and it doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Does anyone know if this feature has been deprecated? Or does it take time to take effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I found that the "Assistant" field in User Profile still does allow the designated user to edit the user's profile.  However, I could not find an "Edit Profile" button to edit, I had to hack my own Edit Profile URL and change it to the ID of the user whose profile I wanted to edit.

Example:
https://[tenant]-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/EditProfile.aspx?UserSettingsProvider=[guid]&ReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2F[tenant]%2Dmy%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2FPersonImmersive%2Easpx&accountname=i%3A0%23%2Ef%7Cmembership%7C[accountname] ) - The only part I needed to change from my Edit Profile link was the account name part at the end.

Comment: I tried that too and found that it only showed my profile. Do you have a sample URL that worked for you?

Comment: Added example url

Comment: I tried that exact approach. Changing the [accountname] had no effect. The profile returned was still the logged in user.

Comment: Odd, it worked for us! I added one of my co-workers as my assistant and he was able to go in and modify my user profile.  I just tried it again and it definitely is loading the correct user profile data.